# OptaPlanner - Cloud Balance additonal hard-constraint

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I am new for OptaPlanner.
My allocation problem is very similar to "Cloud Balance" problem given in the examples of OptaPlanner. But with one additonal hard-constraint.

The **Processes can be** **grouped** and the processes in the same group should NOT be allocated to the same  CPU.

Should this constraint be in the score calculator (`EasyScoreCalculator`). Can it check if the process group is allocated to same CPU in a solution and score it?

Is there any other better approach for this, like using ValueSelector?

And I am getting a solution by default even when processes cannot be allocated to the CPU (because of constraints). Is this how the planner works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
class Service {} // ProcessGroup
class Process {
    private Service service;
    ... // Existing properties
}
```

Then the drl looks something like this:

```
when
    Process($id : id, $s : service, $c : computer)
    Process(id > $id, service == $s, computer == $c)
then
    // hard constraint broken
    ...
end
```

or you can use EasyJavaScoreCalculation instead too of course

Comment: Also take a look at the MachineReassignment example, that has a bunch of constraint types like this one, even more advanced.

Comment: Thank you @Geoffrey, for DRL solution.This should work for me. I am adjusting the pattern `id > $id` to `id != $id`

Comment: With !=  you're going to count each hard constraint violation twice. But you probably won't notice that as you'll get a feasible solution with hard score 0, so 0 times 2 is still 0. So it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you @Geoffrey. I shall revert my change. But only PlanningEntity(Process) is visible in drools, the fact (Computer) is not available. I am inserting Computer from the Process entities. What is wrong with my approach ?